# Is it possible to use Windows 7 Themes on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, themes

Just out of curiosity, I would like to try getting the Windows 7 Aero theme source files and putting them on Windows 8.1 to see if it would work. Does anyone know if it would be possible to do such a thing? I have access to a Windows 7 installation to get the files, but what I need to know is where they are stored. I understand that with the release of Windows 8 Microsoft changed something with theme extensions, but I have a feeling that Microsoft still has compatibility built in for Windows 7 themes.

Comment: Aero does not even exist in Windows 8 so what you want isn't possible

Comment: I don't think you understand. I know that Aero does not exist in Windows 8, so I was thinking of grabbing the Windwows 7 Aero theme files and putting them on my Windows 8.1 machine to get the Aero that I want.

Comment: It's not going to work.  The visual effects no longer even exist

Comment: I would start by this suggestion http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-to-use-windows-8-bootloader-instead-of-ubuntu/f0fd35e3-43f8-45eb-8b83-966a306bcc86

Comment: Ramhound is right. Aero does not exist in Windows 8. There is however a theme hack you could do, though I'm not sure if it works in 8.1, that brings the Aero Glass effect back. But its really distorted and buggy.

Comment: @Ramhound: `The visual effects no longer even exist`??? Microsoft did not delete any Aero code in Windows 8 - they simply turned off transparency for window borders. If you had run the Win 8 previews, you would have seen how Microsoft gradually modified the window borders...

Comment: I don't use beta versions of Windows and disabled I removed the outcome is the same windows 7 theme files are not compatible with windows 8. A great deal changed be the preview and RTM most were permanently changed

Comment: @BullDozier1337 If you are talking about the AeroLite theme that Microsoft made and then opted to not include but left the source files for, I have already used that hack, and it is not even remotely Aero.

Comment: @DavidB, no I was talking about this trick: http://www.howtogeek.com/128630/how-to-enable-aero-glass-style-transparency-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work. The layout of the theme has changed between Windows 7 and 8 and even between Windows 8 and 8.1.

You need 3rd party [themes like this one](http://damonkeyoncrack.deviantart.com/art/Aero7-V2-for-Windows-8-8-429412929):

[image]

http://damonkeyoncrack.deviantart.com/art/Aero7-V2-for-Windows-8-8-429412929

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it still does.  I am using the [Angry Birds](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/angry-birds-download-theme) theme from Microsoft's site.

> I have access to a Windows 7 installation to get the files, but what I need to know is where they are stored.

On your local system, they are stored in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`.

It has an extension of `themepack`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 themes work in Windows 8 & 8.1 except for the Aero effects. If you take any Windows 7 theme file and run it in Windows 8, it will install successfully and it will be used as the default theme in Windows 8.

What will work exactly the same is the following:

1. the wallpapers
2. the sound scheme
3. the mouse cursors (as long as they are not using Aero effects)
4. the screensaver

Aero is all about transparency and effects related to it. Transparency is gone from Windows 8 and, without special hacks that may impact the stability of the operating system, it won't work.

You can find a very good article, explaining all the differences regarding themes in the two OSes, here: [What's New About Windows 8 Themes? Why They Don't Work in Windows 7?](http://www.7tutorials.com/whats-different-about-windows-8-themes-why-they-dont-work-windows-7)